# Serial number to timestamp in excel

Tags: excel, excel-2007

I have a numbers like **20160715082219000000000** and i want to convert into timestamp like **2016-07-15 08:22:19** and delete that remaining **0**'s.Please suggest how to do this conversion in excel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following formula for the number in cell **A1**

```
=DATE(LEFT(A1*10^-9&"",4),MID(A1*10^-9&"",5,2),MID(A1*10^-9&"",7,2))+TIME(MID(A1*10^-9&"",9,2),MID(A1*10^-9&"",11,2),MID(A1*10^-9&"",13,2))
```

This will output a number that represents a date and time, so `20160715082219` is represented by `42566.34883`. Apply custom formatting to this cell (right click>format cells>custom) and type the following string in to the `Type:` field

```
yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss
```

And you will get the result:

```
2016-07-15 08:22:19
```

As required

Answer (score -1):

This is a solution that worked for me. I know there would be an optimized solution with less amount code and string manipultaion. Suggestions are welcome.

```
Dim Val As String
Dim StrL As String
Dim FinalVal As String
'Store the value in a string
Val = "20160715082219000000000"

'Pick first 4 digits: yyyy
StrL = Left(Val, 4)
'Store the year value in a final string
FinalVal = StrL & "-"
'Trim first 4 digits
Val = Right(Val, (Len(Val) - 4))

'Pick first 2 digits from the trimmed string val: mm
StrL = Left(Val, 2)
'Store the month value in a final string
FinalVal = FinalVal & StrL & "-"
'Trim first 2 digits
Val = Right(Val, (Len(Val) - 2))

'Pick first 2 digits from the trimmed string val: dd
StrL = Left(Val, 2)
'Store the day value in a final string
FinalVal = FinalVal & StrL & " "
'Trim first 2 digits
Val = Right(Val, (Len(Val) - 2))

'Pick first 2 digits from the trimmed string val: HH
StrL = Left(Val, 2)
'Store the hour value in a final string
FinalVal = FinalVal & StrL & ":"
'Trim first 2 digits
Val = Right(Val, (Len(Val) - 2))

'Pick first 2 digits from the trimmed string val: MM
StrL = Left(Val, 2)
'Store the mins value in a final string
FinalVal = FinalVal & StrL & ":"
'Trim first 2 digits
Val = Right(Val, (Len(Val) - 2))

'Pick first 2 digits from the trimmed string val: ss
StrL = Left(Val, 2)
'Store the month value in a final string
FinalVal = FinalVal & StrL
'Trim first 2 digits
Val = Right(Val, (Len(Val) - 2))

'Discard remaining characters
Val = ""
StrL = ""
MsgBox FinalVal
```

Comment: Thanks for information!! Time being i want excel formula. can you please suggest me something in excel?